# Array Check with incomplete data

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Im trying to check up agianst an array, my code is the following

```
$coax = array("86.52", "85.218", "178.155", "212.10", "212.112", "62.107", "5.206");


    if(in_array("86.52.16.14", $coax))
            {
              echo "jubii";
                   } else
                   {
                   echo "nej nej nej";
                   }
        }
```

But my problem is that i have to check xx.xx.xx.xx against xx.xx in the array. is there a work around for that ?

Comment: What do you mean by have to check xx.xx.xx.xx against xx.xx? obviously these don't match.

Comment: Are you always matching at the beginning? Or should it also match `"16.14"` in the array?

Comment: It because im taking ip´s from an csv, and the IP´s are complete xx.xx.xx.xx But i only have the start of the scopes in the array, and i want to check if the ip matches that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, testing if the input IP begins with the array element.

```
$found = false;
foreach ($coax as $x) {
    if (strpos("86.52.16.14", $x) === 0) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    echo "jubii";
} else {
    echo "nej nej nej";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could explode out the first two pieces of each array and check it against the coax array like so:

```
$coax = array("86.52", "85.218", "178.155", "212.10", "212.112", "62.107", "5.206");
$checkValue = "86.52.16.14";
$tempArray = explode(".",$checkValue);
$checkValueFormatted = $tempArray[0] .".".$tempArray[1];

if(in_array($checkValueFormatted, $coax))
            {
              echo "jubii";
                   } else
                   {
                   echo "nej nej nej";
                   }
        }
}
```

If you make $checkValue an array you can throw in a foreach on that and check multiple values at once. You could also throw in a foreach so you can check multiple values quicker like so....

```
    $coax = array("86.52", "85.218", "178.155", "212.10", "212.112", "62.107", "5.206");
    $checkValues = array("86.52.16.14", "42.12.1231.1231", "212.10.123.123");

    foreach ($checkValues as $value) {

    $tempArray = explode(".",$value);
    $checkValueFormatted = $tempArray[0] .".".$tempArray[1];
    if(in_array($checkValueFormatted, $coax))
                {
                  echo "jubii";
                       } else
                       {
                       echo "nej nej nej";
                       }
            }
    }
}
```